# Excel File to database by using zend framework

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework2

I want to read an excel file and save the data in database. I tried this in pure PHP by using `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader` it is working fine, but when I am using the same code in Zend Framework 2 it is not working. Giving no data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using composer to load zendframework, try to load phpExcel lib too using composer.php.

Run following command from command prompt

```
php composer.phar selfupdate

php composer.phar require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Use in Controller

```
$excelObj = new \PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could export the excel file to a `csv` file (for example `data.csv`) and then you can do it with an SQL query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Check [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/) for more information

Comment: Is this procedure can be done zend doctrine and .xls file can be uploaded or not

Comment: @BeDeveloper Zend Framework 2 is a php framework so whatever you can do in php you can also do in ZF2. The question is more how much custom code you would have to write for this. You didn't talk about upload in your question at all, you should add such important information to your question next time (read also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). If those are files uploaded by clients and you will put the data it in your database you should be very careful since it is a perfect way for SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks alot i will be careful next time